# Attribute Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying this code but I keep getting the same result, which is:

**if Prep.endswith ('jpg'):
AttributeError:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'**

```
  import re
result = "hey(14).jpg"

Prep = print(re.sub(r" ?\([^)]+\)", "", result))

if Prep.endswith ('jpg'):
    Caption = print(Prep.replace("jpg", "is jpg"))
elif Prep.endswith ('png'):
    Caption = print(Prep.replace("png", "is png"))
elif Prep.endswith ('gif'):
    Caption = print(Prep.replace("gif", "is gif"))
else :
    Caption = print("Unknown")
```

I dont know where this comes from.

Any help will be apreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
Prep = print(re.sub(r" ?\([^)]+\)", "", result))
```

You're assigning the return value of `print` to `Prep` and then later trying to use it. The problem is that `print` doesn't return anything -- in other words, it always returns `None`.

You want this:

```
Prep = re.sub(r" ?\([^)]+\)", "", result)
print(Prep)
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, since I am new at coding and learing "the hard way", I was not aware of this, I really thank you for your help